# Variable in powershell AD commands issue

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I have searched around (including) this forum and seen comments about this but can not get it to work.

I have a variable in PS `$user.accountname = Aaron.street"`

But as bellow if i type the name in full it works but not using the variable. I have tried so mane suggestions from searching this forum but nothing seems to work.

```
    PS D:\Lync PS scripts> Get-adUser -Filter "name -like 'Aaron Street'"


DistinguishedName : CN=aaron street,OU=Full_time,OU=Staff,OU=Accounts,OU=.........
Enabled           : True
GivenName         : aaron
Name              : aaron street
ObjectClass       : user
ObjectGUID        : 037c744b-63fa-4a18-adb3-........
SamAccountName    : street
SID               : S-1-5-21-33161136-...........
Surname           : street
UserPrincipalName : street@...........




PS D:\Lync PS scripts> Get-adUser -Filter "name -like '$user.Accountname'"

PS D:\Lync PS scripts> Write-Host $user.AccountName
Aaron Street
```

What I want is to find the user and then update a property using another variable "$user.number" So my full command would be

```
get-aduser -filter "name -like '$user.accountname'" | set-aduser -Replace @{Officephone = $user.Number}
```

Any thoughts on where I am going wrong with using the variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [subexpression](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html) to expand the variable correctly

```
Get-adUser -Filter "name -like '$($user.Accountname)'"
```

Comment: Perfect, I will look that up later (PS in not my skill set as you can tell) what its doing. But in the mean time thank you very much for your help.